# Visual studio 6 to studio 2010 with an activex control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, activex, porting, visual-c++-6

I am trying to convert a visual studio 6 project to Visual studio 2010.

There is an activex control on the dialog box. it works fine in Studio 6.

However it fails in

```
BOOL COleControlContainer::FillListSitesOrWnds(_AFX_OCC_DIALOG_INFO* pOccDlgInfo)
```

If I try to create the control in OnInitDialog like below dynamically it returns 0

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
BOOL m = m_obChartCtrl.Create(_T("test"),WS_CHILD |WS_VISIBLE,CRect (10,10,200,200),this,ID_FIRSTAXGC);
```

Comment: Try drawing that control on a vc10 dialog directly and see if that draws?